# Conjunction Usage?

Tags: conjunctions, syntactic-analysis, conjunction-reduction

I was recently writing a paper and I was wondering what is the most appropriate usage of the conjunction *and*

There are leftovers in both his house and in his office

There are leftovers in both his house and his office

There are leftovers in both his house and office

Which of these is correct, and what's the most general rule for situations like these? Thanks!

Comment: The first one is syntactically incorrect.  If you "distribute" the first "in" to the alternative clauses, you get "...leftovers both in his house and in in his office."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All three variants are quite common in speech, but in writing I would recommend either "in both his house and his office" or a more formal option that you didn't list, namely "both in his house and in his office"). These have a pleasantly parallel "both X and Y" structure, whereas in the other versions the *both* isn't quite introducing the coordination, leaving the syntax a bit muddled.